# Audio html5 loop pause

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I would like set a loop with 10 minutes to delay. After start and finish, I need to use a 10 minutes to delay before it will start again automatically.

```
$audio_code =
'<div style="display: none;">' .
'<audio id="war_soundy_audio_player" preload="auto" ' . $auto_play . ' ' . $audio_loop . '>' .
'<audio controls="controls" onloadeddata="var audioPlayer = this; setTimeout(function() { audioPlayer.play(); }, 0000)">' .
'      <source id="war_soundy_audio_player_source" src="' . $audio_file_url . '" type="' . $audio_type . '">' .
'  </audio>' .
'</div>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the delay to 20 minutes

```
var audioPlayer = this;
 setTimeout(function() {
 audioPlayer.play(); 
}, 10*60*1000)
```

also you can remove this

```
<audio id="war_soundy_audio_player" preload="auto" ' . $auto_play . ' ' . $audio_loop . '>' .
```

If you want it to start on load add `autoplay` in the audio tag ,also add 10*60*1000 add the time that is spent the the audio is player for example if audio is 5 minutes change to 15*60*1000

Comment: I need to start with autoplay and after a 20 minutes to delay. But the sound needs to start automatically

Comment: @andress  for 20 minutes change 10*60*1000 to duration of the song +20 minutes ,add autoplay in audio tag to autostart

Comment: It is working but when change page in wordpress start from autoplay.

Answer (score 0):

It is working, but I need to use the same delay also when page is changed or new wordpress pages/posts